# Define a command differently in inline vs display mode

Tags: math-mode, macros, inline, displaystyle

I would like to have a command `\catlim` which behaves differently in inline vs in display mode. Namely, in inline mode, it should be equivalent to `\lim` and in display mode, it should be equivalent to `\varprojlim` (or some nicer version of it) with arrow below the limit. Here is an example what the result should look like:

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\begin{document}

Inline \(\lim_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / p^i \mathbb{Z}\) and display:
\begin{equation*}
  \varprojlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / p^i \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Just don't forget that inline math style is also used in displayed math, e.g. fractions and the standard cases env.

Comment: Another alternative to the solutions below is the plain TeX command `\mathchoice`.

Comment: @Davislor:  You are right, of course, but, as I say in my answer, we cannot tell exactly what the OP’s idea of “being in display mode” is.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Since you are using LuaTeX, you can simply query `\mathstyle`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\newcommand\catlim{%
    \ifcase\mathstyle
        % 0 = \displaystyle
        \expandafter\varprojlim
    \or
        % 1 = \crampeddisplaystyle
        \expandafter\varprojlim
    \else
        % all other styles
        \expandafter\lim
    \fi}

\begin{document}

Inline \(\catlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / p^i \mathbb{Z}\) and display:
\begin{equation*}
  \catlim_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{Z} / p^i \mathbb{Z}.
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It’s not clear what you want to do when you explicitly reset the math style.  The following solution, which requires `amsmath` but works also with the “classical” typesetting engines, discriminates based on the `\if@display` switch.  This purposely ignores the math style (`\displaystyle` vs. other styles), and decides which command to use (`\varprojlim` vs. `\lim`) considering only if the formula is being displayed or typeset in-line.

I insist that it is not clear from your question whether you consider this a bug or a feature.  See also [@daleif’s comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512706/define-a-command-differently-in-inline-vs-display-mode/512713#comment1296554_512706).

The code:

```
% My standard header for TeX.SX answers:
\documentclass[a4paper]{article} % To avoid confusion, let us explicitly 
                                 % declare the paper format.

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}         % Not always necessary, but recommended.
% End of standard header.  What follows pertains to the problem at hand.

\usepackage{mathtools} % also loads "amsmath"
\usepackage{amsfonts}

\makeatletter

\newcommand*\catlim{%
  \relax\if@display
    \expandafter\varprojlim
  \else
    \expandafter\lim
  \fi
}

\makeatother

\newcommand*{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}}
\newcommand*{\N}{\numberset{N}}
\newcommand*{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}



\begin{document}

In line:
\( \catlim_{i\in\N} \Z/p^{i}\Z \).

In line, but with \verb|\displaystyle|:
\( \displaystyle \catlim_{i\in\N} \frac{\Z}{p^{i}\Z} \).

In display:
\[
    \catlim_{i\in\N} \frac{\Z}{p^{i}\Z}
\]

In display, but with \verb|\textstyle|:
\[
    \textstyle \catlim_{i\in\N} \Z/p^{i}\Z
\]

An example with \texttt{cases} (starred version requires the 
\textsf{mathtools} package):
\[
    G =
        \begin{cases*}
            \catlim_{i\in\N} \frac{\Z}{p^{i}\Z} & first case \\
            \catlim_{i\in\N} \frac{\Z}{q^{i}\Z} & second case
        \end{cases*}
\]
Note how the fraction is typeset: this too shows that
\verb|\textstyle| is in force.

\end{document}
```

The printout:

[image: Output of the code]

Comment: +1 but there is a point you might want to clarify: `\if@display` won't work with something like `$\displaystyle...$`. Just to be thorough.

Comment: @campa:  Thank you for your suggestion; please see edit.