# How to pass an argument to lua tex.print with maths

Tags: math-mode, delimiters, lua, arguments, luacode

I want to create a blank exercise, in which answers can be text or mathematical expression, and to have below a list of all answers in disorder.

In the MWE i made with LUA, the text appears below as expected, but I don't know how to have math expressions like $\pi$ or $\frac{2}{3}$.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}

\directlua{list={}; }
\def\hide#1{
  \directlua{ table.insert(list,"#1") }
  \textcolor{red}{#1} % final version will have white instead of red
}

\begin{document}

Try with \hide{text}.\\
Try with \hide{ LUA \directlua{ tex.sprint(math.pi); } }.\\
Try with \hide{ \bf{command} }.\\
Try with \hide{ "math mode $\pi$" }.\par\vspace{\baselineskip}

\rule[2ex]{\linewidth}{0.5pt}

\directlua{ for i,v in ipairs(list) do 
    tex.print(v);
    tex.print("\noexpand\\\\");
    end }

\end{document}
```

[image: result]

---

EDIT: I updated my code thanks to Mico, and i made the answers to appears in boxes. The problem comes when the hidden answer is a part of a math expression and surrounded with delimiters, like the last two exemples: perenthesis and curly braces of fraction.

The resulting errors both point to the end of last \luaexec block:
"Missing $ inserted." and "Extra }, or forgotten $."

I wonder if there is any way to solve this. Here is the code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastringN' and '\luaexec' macros
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\directlua{list={}} % intialize a Lua table object
\def\hide#1{%
   \directlua{ table.insert(list,\luastringN{#1})}%
   \textcolor{red}{#1}% final version will have white instead of red
}

\begin{document}

Try with \hide{text}.\par
Try with \hide{LUA \directlua{ tex.sprint(math.pi)}}.\par
Try with \hide{\textbf{command}}.\par
Try with \hide{math mode $\pi$ inside}.\par
Try with inside math mode $\hide{\pi}$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=( \ \hide{5-x^2}\ ) e^x$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=\frac{ \hide{4-\sqrt{x}} }{e^x}$.\par

\vspace{\baselineskip}\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}

\luaexec{
  for i,v in ipairs(list) do
      tex.sprint ( '\\fbox{'..v..'} \\ ' )
  end
}

\end{document}
```

Again, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: For your EDIT, which really is a new question and is longer than your original query, you should have posted an *entirely new query* rather than modify an existing query. (For sure, I became aware of your massive edit only after you unaccepted my answer.) How was I supposed to foresee the additional requirements you would come up with when I wrote my initial answer? As a result of your edit, my answer is pretty much useless/meaningless for future readers of your now-greatly-modified query. I have therefore decided to delete my answer.

Comment: I was not sure what to do. Your answer was good, for the original post. I should have left this question as solved and made a new post. I will do that tomorrow. How can i repair? If you mention again the use of \luastringN (even shortly), i will accept it again. My apologies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combining the ideas of:

- [\newcommand: How to determine if in math mode (and then include $ $)?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/46492/newcommand-how-to-determine-if-in-math-mode-and-then-include)
- [Define a command differently in inline vs display mode](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512706/define-a-command-differently-in-inline-vs-display-mode)

You can do something like this

[image]

```
% !TeX TS-program = lualatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{luacode} % for '\luastringN' and '\luaexec' macros
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

\directlua{list={}} % intialize a Lua table object

% select version by using \finaltrue or \finalfalse
\newif\iffinal
%\finaltrue
\finalfalse

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_set:Npn \hide #1 {
    % check if in math mode
    \relax\ifmmode
        \directlua{ table.insert(list,\luastringN{$#1$})}
    \else
        % normal text mode
        \directlua{ table.insert(list,\luastringN{#1})}
    \fi
    % instead of making things white, we simply create a placeholder with the same dimensions
    % this prevents the learners from copying the answer from a PDF viewer
    \iffinal
        \phantom{#1}
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \fi
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Try with \hide{text}.\par
Try with \hide{LUA \directlua{ tex.sprint(math.pi)}}.\par
Try with \hide{\textbf{command}}.\par
Try with \hide{math mode $\pi$ inside}.\par
Try with inside math mode $\hide{\pi}$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=( \ \hide{5-x^2}\ ) e^x$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=\frac{ \hide{4-\sqrt{x}} }{e^x}$.\par

\vspace{\baselineskip}\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}


\begin{luacode}
    for i,v in ipairs(list) do
        --texio.write_nl(v)
        tex.sprint ( '\\fbox{'..v..'} \\ ' )
    end
\end{luacode}


\end{document}
```

The second link also indicates that it is possible to process math styles differently, but due to the reasons explained [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/how-to-capture-the-current-math-style), it is not working very ideally.

As a matter of fact, it is possible to achieve your goals with LaTeX only. Try the code below.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{expl3}

\setlength\parindent{0pt}
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.5}
\everymath{\displaystyle}

% select version by using \finaltrue or \finalfalse
\newif\iffinal
%\finaltrue
\finalfalse

\ExplSyntaxOn

\seq_new:N \g_my_keys_seq

\cs_set:Npn \hide #1 {
    % check if in math mode
    \relax\ifmmode
        \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_my_keys_seq {$#1$}
    \else
        % normal text mode
        \seq_gput_right:Nn \g_my_keys_seq {#1}
    \fi
    % instead of making things white, we simply create a placeholder with the same dimensions
    % this prevents the learners from copying the answer from a PDF viewer
    \iffinal
        \phantom{#1}
    \else
        \textcolor{red}{#1}
    \fi
}

\tl_set:Nx \pivalue {\fp_use:N \c_pi_fp}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{document}

Try with \hide{text}.\par
Try with \hide{LUA \pivalue}.\par
Try with \hide{\textbf{command}}.\par
Try with \hide{math mode $\pi$ inside}.\par
Try with inside math mode $\hide{\pi}$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=( \ \hide{5-x^2}\ ) e^x$.\par
Try with inside math delimiters $f(x)=\frac{ \hide{4-\sqrt{x}} }{e^x}$.\par

\vspace{\baselineskip}\hrule\vspace{\baselineskip}

\ExplSyntaxOn
% shuffle keys
\seq_shuffle:N \g_my_keys_seq
\seq_map_inline:Nn \g_my_keys_seq {
    \fbox{#1}\ 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thank Alan you for those solutions, both functionnal. I might need some time to understand those...

I've seen that 'texio.write' deals with console and log. Does that mean you put if for debugging purpose? I couldn't see the difference in the log file.

Comment: Yes, it is for debugging. You can safely delete it.

Comment: The problem about your code is when the material gets saved in the Lua table, it does not know whether the material is in math mode or not. I added some kind of conditional branch to automatically surround the code with `$$` if the command is called in math mode.

Comment: Yes, i understood that. I'ts rather the expl3 commands that i've never seen before. I need to learn latex3 from scratch (and maybe also a lot of tex and some of latex2).